# Website opens on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ubuntu-16.04

**THIS IS NOT A PROGRAMMING QUESTION BUT I DIDN'T KNOW WHICH FORUM TO ASK THIS IN. SO FEEL FREE TO MOVE THIS TO THE CONCERNED SO FORUM**

I'm trying to open the website: https://material.io/icons/

It opens on my firefox, but shows a blank screen and multiple errors on console. Opening it in incognito mode doesn't help either.

Chrome: Version 58.0.3029.110 (Ubuntu)

Firefox: Version 56.0 (Ubuntu)

**FIREFOX**

[image]

**CHROME**

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Is Chrome up-to-date? Did you alter any security settings/disabling CORS, etc.? Does this happen everytime you try?

Comment: @Cyphrags, yea everytime

Comment: Even when shift+f5 ?

Comment: @Cyphrags,yup. even in incognito mode